# Why does subplot_kws projection hides the lat and lon?

Tags: matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy, facet-grid

With a xarray dataset, how can I use FacetGrid with a specific cartopy projection and keep the latitude and longitude values along the axis?

I was trying to use faceting as described in the [user-guide here](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/plotting.html#faceting). As soon as I try to give the subplots a specific projection, I lose the lat and lon values on the axis

here is an example:

```
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

airtemps = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")
air = airtemps.air - 273.15
t = air.isel(time=slice(0, 365 * 4, 250) )
g_simple = t.plot.contourf(x="lon", y="lat", col="time", col_wrap=3,
                           transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                           subplot_kws={"projection": ccrs.PlateCarree()},
                           levels=51,
)
```

[image]

but if I comment out the projection line

```
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

airtemps = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")
air = airtemps.air - 273.15
t = air.isel(time=slice(0, 365 * 4, 250) )
g_simple = t.plot.contourf(x="lon", y="lat", col="time", col_wrap=3,
                           #  subplot_kws={"projection": ccrs.PlateCarree()},
                           levels=51,
)
```

[image]

Why does it happen? and how can i fix this?

Comment: The aspect ratio of the plot is not = 1. Try `ax.set_aspect('equal')` where `ax` is the axes of the plot. In your case, (a wild guess) `g_simple` may be used as the axes.

Comment: well the map does not have equal size lon and lat so i would not expect a projection to make the aspect ratio equal.In the example the lat range is (°15-75°), and the lon range (200°-330° measured eastwards from 0°)

Comment: g_simple is a `xarray.plot.facetgrid.FacetGrid` object. From `matplotlib.pyplot` I got ax by using `plt.gca().aspect('equal')` but it throws an error because 'GeoAxesSubplot' has no `aspect` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartopy turns the axis labels off by default because they do not make sense for all of Cartopy's projections.  You can turn them on again by using the `set_visible` method on each axis.  I also here added coastlines because I think it helps make it obvious where we are looking.

It seems that xarray is using [`tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html) underneath somewhere.  I couldn't figure out how to make space for the labels and keep the colorbar in the right place with `tight_layout` so I switched to using the more modern [compressed layout](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/constrainedlayout_guide.html#grids-of-fixed-aspect-ratio-axes-compressed-layout).  It turns out you can't switch the layout engine in this way if you already have a colorbar, so I turned the colorbar off initially in the call to `contour` and added back after switching layout engines.

```
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

airtemps = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")
air = airtemps.air - 273.15
t = air.isel(time=slice(0, 365 * 4, 250) )
g_simple = t.plot.contourf(x="lon", y="lat", col="time", col_wrap=3,
                           transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                           subplot_kws={"projection": ccrs.PlateCarree()},
                           levels=51, add_colorbar=False
)

for ax in g_simple.axs.flat:  # loop through the map axes
    subplotspec = ax.get_subplotspec()
    if subplotspec.is_last_row():
        ax.xaxis.set_visible(True)
    if subplotspec.is_first_col():
        ax.yaxis.set_visible(True)
    ax.coastlines()
    
g_simple.fig.set_layout_engine("compressed")
g_simple.fig.get_layout_engine().set(h_pad=0.2)  # More vertical space between maps
g_simple.add_colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image: [image upload seems to be currently broken across StackOverflow]]

Comment: thanks! it is looking good. Minor point i get a `DeprecationWarning` suggesting to use axs instead of axes, ie `g_simple.axs.flat`.

Comment: A yes, edit made!

Comment: but unfortunately it is not recognising one command `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_layout_engine'`. that might be due to my environment though

Comment: @dodohjk what Matplotlib version do you have?  Compressed layout was introduced at v3.6.  Before that you might try `fig.set_constrained_layout(True)` (compressed layout is a special case of constrained layout).

Comment: i have Matplotlib 3.5.3. `set_constrained_layout(True)` works fine